# Unable to plot p values when using facet.by from ggsurvplot. Error message: "variable lengths differ"

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression, survival, survminer

I have a problem that I don't know how to solve. And it seems to be related to my data set (or is it?). Indeed, I am actually able to plot different p values when using `facet.by` when I use your example from [issue#205](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/205) via the "colon" data set. However,it does not work with my data set that is available on my Github profile here (https://github.com/CroixJeremy2/Data-frame-for-stack-overflow.git).

**Expected behavior**

I would like to be able to plot different p values as in [issue#205](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/205) with my data set.

**Actual behavior**

I am only able to plot the curves via `facet.by`. But I can't plot the p values that should be automatically calculated for a log-rank test. Instead, an error message is returned in my R console saying:

```
"Error in model.frame.default(formula = Survival ~ Sex, data = list(ID = c(147L, :"
"les longueurs des variables diffèrent (trouvé pour 'Sex')"
# the last line translated from French to English means:
"variable lengths differ (found for Sex)"
```

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

```
library(survival)
Survival = Surv(time = D$Age, event = D$outcome)
library(survminer)
fit = survfit(data = D, formula = Survival ~ Sex + Genotype)
ggsurvplot(fit = fit, data = D, pval = TRUE, facet.by = 'Genotype') #error message
ggsurvplot(fit = fit, data = D, facet.by = 'Genotype') #curves can be plotted
```

**Remarks**

Note that the `survdiff()` function works perfectly on my data sets in order to calculate p values from log-rank tests. Therefore, I do not know if I am doing something wrong in `ggsurvplot()` (most likely hypothesis) or if there is something wrong in the `ggsurvplot()` function itself (unlikely).

```
survdiff(data = D, subset = D$Ctrl, formula = Survival ~ Sex)
survdiff(data = D, subset = D$nKO, formula = Survival ~ Sex)
survdiff(data = D, subset = D$CRE_Ctrl, formula = Survival ~ Sex)
#works fine, p value returned, no message/warning/error returned.
```

Moreover, the variable lengths seems equal... And I don't have any "NA" values in my dataframe... So I really don't understand why I have this error message...

```
sapply(D,function(x) length(x))
# length = 298 for all my variables...
```

Thanks in advance for your response and help,